Bug in tikz-3dplot ? \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin and \node not working together
It seems that \node is not working correctly with \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin although \draw node is: when using \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(Point)}, all nodes created with \node are placed at (Point) regardless of the coordinates specified for the node.
Here is a MWE :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{200}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, scale=2]

\draw [->, thick] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node [left] {$x$};
\draw [->, thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node [left] {$y$};
\draw [->, thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node [left] {$z$};

\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0};

% Uncomment to reveal the problem
% \coordinate (Point) at (0,0,1);
% \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(Point)}

\node [tdplot_rotated_coords, circle, fill, blue] at (1,0,0) {};
\draw [tdplot_rotated_coords] (1,0,0) node [fill, red] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

With the commented lines, the two nodes are at the right place :

When I uncomment them, this is what I get :

I would have expected the blue node to be where the red is…
